# How to split polygons with another polygon and inheritage data?

Tags: postgis, sql

Let's say that we have two tables with polygons representing areas. Table A and Table B. Geometries from table A represents both the valid and invalid areas. And the geometries in table B  represents the invalid ones.

For example, lets say that the geometries from table A represent, harvesting fields, and table B represents roads, shacks and generally areas that the harvesting is impossible for w/e reason (as polygons). Table B represents some kind of mask that's has being digitized differently.

The problem arises that the mask, can pass through many fields. So I want to clip that mask (Table B), with the field polygon (Table A) to create a new set (Table C) consisting with the  geometries that represents the masks 'per field' along with the name of the field it was cut from.

This can be done by

`create tableC as (select st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom) geom from tableA as a, tableB as b);`

But I have troubles on how to select the tableA.name as well and transferring it to tableC.

the selection part of an ideal querry would be like this:

`create tableC as (select st_intersection(a.geom,g.geom) geom, tableA.name as name from .... );`

A sample defintion of table C is the following:

```
Column     |   Type      | 
gid        | int         |
geom       | geometry    |  <- st_intersetion(a.geom,b.geom)
name       |varchar(255) |  <- name of the feature of table A which took part in the st_intersection
```

Table A is defined as  following:

```
Column     |   Type      | 
gid        | int         |
name       | varchar(255)|
geom       | geometry    |
```

And Table B as follows:

```
Column     |   Type      | 
gid        | int         |
geom       | geometry    |
```

And for a visual representation :

[image]

Comment: st_intersects returns true/false (vs st_intersection) and your image is confusing, since there is none between A and B. Are their gids really not integers? What have you tried so far?

Comment: My mistake! I wanted to write st_intersection. st_intersection returns a geometrycoletion. I've updated the question.

Comment: Woah, where did the squares came from? What does the circle represent?

Comment: Hmm it seems that the question is not clear enough! i'll try to explain it a bit a more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
CREATE TABLE tableC AS 
  (SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom, a.name AS name 
   FROM tableA AS a, tableB AS b
   WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom));
```

By looking at each intersection separately, you can access all the included data.

Comment: It should be b.geom instead of g.geom in your query

Comment: duh yes, I need to refresh my SQLs.